# Brutal bug "android.process.acore has stopped" doesn't solve after factory reset

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, factory-reset, system-error, bugs, debug

Apparently this bug is prevalent and some are lucky enough to solve it by simply clearing data of Contacts storage but not me. I believe I have tried it all. Even after factory reset (via stock recovery) this error appears immediately after first boot and it keeps popping up non-stop making the phone very hard to use.

[image]

Does anyone know a solid fix for this brutal bug?

Comment: It's usually caused by a modified system app going hey wire , Or a simple permission fix is required

Comment: @user157947 okay but how exactly to fix it?

Comment: I wasn't lucky as well, and I needed to reflash the stock firmware on a S3 Neo.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman This is some crazy shit. I feel for those people who doesn't have a clue on how to flash roms.